# Access multipartProperties in SpringBoot JSP Page

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

i have defined

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=20MB
```

in my application.properties

This configuration is read by

```
package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet;
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.servlet.multipart", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class MultipartProperties {
```

How can i access the MultipartProperties Bean?

I tried

```
<spring:eval expression="@multipartProperties.maxFileSize" />
```

but only get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'multipartProperties' available
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the correct bean

```
<spring:eval expression="@multipartConfigElement.maxFileSize" />
```

i saw it in MultipartAutoConfiguration

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean({ MultipartConfigElement.class, CommonsMultipartResolver.class })
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    return this.multipartProperties.createMultipartConfig();
}
```